# Combine results from separate columns grouped by a specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, select

having a table like this in oracle db:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| VAL1| VAL2| VAL3|  ID |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  A  |     |     |  1  |
-------------------------
|     |  B  |     |  1  |
-------------------------
|     |     |  C  |  1  |
-------------------------
|  X  |     |  Z  |  2  |
-------------------------
|     |  Y  |     |  2  |
-------------------------
|     |  Y  |  Z  |  2  |
-------------------------
|  E  |     |     |  3  |
-------------------------
|     |     |  F  |  3  |
-------------------------
```

How to select from this table (in ORACLE) in order to get following output where all this rows are grouped by ID column?

```
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
    | VAL1| VAL2| VAL3|  ID |
    +-----+-----+-----+-----+
    |  A  |  B  |  C  |  1  |
    -------------------------
    |  X  |  Y  |  Z  |  2  |
    -------------------------
    |  E  |     |  F  |  3  |
    -------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id, max(val1) as val1, max(val2) as val2, max(val3) as val3
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: actually - this (selecting max) is the way I did it, maybe you can suggest a more analytical and clean approach!?

Comment: If you can define "more analytical" and "clean" then we'd stand a better chance!

Comment: @tv . . . Hard to think of anything simpler than this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` combined with an aggregation function, such as `MAX()`.

For example:

```
select
  max(val1) as val1,
  max(val2) as val2,
  max(val3) as val3,
  id
from t
group by id
```